# Django view with two forms not posting one

Tags: django

Im trying to use one form to get data for two different models, to do so, I changed my create view get_context_data function like this:

```
class tarea_crear(CreateView):
    template_name = "crud_tareas/tarea_crear.html"
    form_class = tareaForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tareas:crear-tarea')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(tarea_crear, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = {'audiosForm':audiosForm,'tareaForm':tareaForm}
        return context
```

This allowed me to call both forms on my template, like this: (Dont worry, I remembered the crfs tag and the form)

```
{{form.tareaForm.as_p}}
{{form.audiosForm.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Crear Tarea">
```

I also needed to validate some informationfrom the first form, and I did it like this in the view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    titulo = form.cleaned_data['titulo']
    if not any(i.isdigit() for i in titulo):
             return super(tarea_crear, self).form_valid(self, form)
    return super(tarea_crear, self).form_invalid(self, form)
```

The problem is that when I do the POST of the form, only the first half of the data is actually sent, I know this because I cant call **form.cleaned_data['audios']** in the view without getting an error. Any idea how to handle a View with two forms?

Comment: `as_p` doesn't include the beginning and ending `<form>` tags -- you're supposed to put those in the template yourself.  Where are they?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, I just placed them as an example of how I place the forms in the template, but they are properly used inside a form tag